# Not getting results using SearchExecutor KQL | SharePoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I am trying to get files results using SearchExecutor.

This us the code:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://SERVER NAME"))
            {
                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb(""))
                {

                       KeywordQuery keywordQuery = new KeywordQuery(web);
                       keywordQuery.QueryText = "Author: Moss_User";

                       keywordQuery.KeywordInclusion = KeywordInclusion.AllKeywords;
                       keywordQuery.ResultsProvider = Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchProvider.Default;
                    keywordQuery.TrimDuplicates = false;
                    keywordQuery.EnableStemming = true;
                    keywordQuery.EnablePhonetic = true;
                    keywordQuery.EnableNicknames = false;
                    keywordQuery.IgnoreAllNoiseQuery = true;
                    keywordQuery.Timeout = 60000;
                    keywordQuery.RowLimit = 500;

                      keywordQuery.SelectProperties.Add("author");
                    keywordQuery.SelectProperties.Add("SiteName");

                    SearchExecutor searchExecutor = new SearchExecutor();

                    ResultTableCollection resultTableCollection = searchExecutor.ExecuteQuery(keywordQuery);
                    var resultTables = resultTableCollection.Filter("TableType", KnownTableTypes.RelevantResults);
                    var resultTable = resultTables.FirstOrDefault();
                    retunltDataTable = resultTable.Table;
}}
```

The thing is I am not getting ANY results when searching for:

```
keywordQuery.QueryText ="Author: Moss_User"
```

I am getting resukts only when searching for:

```
keywordQuery.QueryText ="*"
```

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove that whitespace after colon

```
keywordQuery.QueryText ="Author:Moss_User"
```

Also there is tool for testing queries against Sharepoint search API, it can be useful for testing queries without deploying any code

[Sharepoint Search Tool](https://sp2013searchtool.codeplex.com/)